# How to unescape Unicode character in ActionScript 3 AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, unicode, escaping

I'm having a problem with "&".

Basically I haven't been able to escape this correctly in Flash AS3, however I did find this link which seems helpful:
http://www.smithmediafusion.com/blog/?p=343

**Test page:
http://touchstormdigital.com/leon/testing/**

Here are my current functions:

```
try {
    varHome   = this.loaderInfo.parameters.home;
    homeImage = this.loaderInfo.parameters.homeImage;
    homeTitle = this.loaderInfo.parameters.homeText; // Get the Video Title
    // Title  = "Quick & easy chicken recipes for dinner"
} catch (e:Error) {
    varHome   = "false";
    homeBool  = false;
}
```

The Search and Replace function:

```
// Home player test search & replace ampersand
private function replaceString(str:String, find:String, replace:String):String 
{
    var startIndex:Number = 0;
    var oldIndex:Number   = 0;
    var newString:String  = "";

    while ((startIndex = str.indexOf(find, startIndex)) != -1)
    {
        newString += str.substring(oldIndex, startIndex) + replace;
        oldIndex = startIndex += find.length;
    }

    return((newString == "") ? str : newString);
}
```

And then how I'm using it

```
private function drawSplash():void
{
    sp = new ScreenButton();

    replaceString(homeTitle,"&", "\\u0026");

    sp.drawScreenButton(playerW, playerH, homeBool, homeImage, homeTitle);
    sp.addEventListener("onPlay", vd.playVideo);
    sp.addEventListener("embedSplash", hideSplash);
    stage.addChild(sp);
}
```

I think this is where the problem is:

```
replaceString(homeTitle,"&", "\\u0026");
```

I've also tried this:

```
replaceString(homeTitle,"&", String.fromCharCode(38));
```

---

**GOAL**
Grab "Quick & easy chicken recipes for dinner" and display it

Still displaying just "Quick"

**Test page:
http://touchstormdigital.com/leon/testing/**

---

**UPDATE! Another simple fix found and no need to change title!**

In addition to The_asMan's answer which works, but requires the text/copy to be written all weird, I found this simple piece of javascript that does the job:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp

**How I'm using it:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var homeText = "Quick & easy - chicken' recipes for dinner?!=+";
    var fixed = encodeURIComponent(homeText);

</script>
```

**And then in the Flashvars area:**

```
so.addVariable("homeText", fixed);
```

**Then in Flash:**

```
unescape(homeTitle);
```

**Woot!**

Comment: Have you tried escape(homeTitle)

Comment: BTW, your test page shows good results on my browser

Comment: @The_asMan yup that was the first thing I tried :( Also I did find a fix, but it's on the HTML side of things, & has to be written as %26. So I'm still looking for a fix inside of Flash

Comment: Well I don't know what to tell you. I visited the link you supplied and I see the full text "Quick & easy chicken recipes for dinner" It does not look broken at all to me. The only other thing I can think of is the font on the machine you are look at it on is not available. Try to embed the font?

Comment: It must have been a cashed version of the HTML fix, I've since removed that, and now it's stuck at "Quick%20" when I try escaping

Comment: Odd I see it all fubar now. Oh wait a minute I see what you are doing now. You are getting them from flash vars. The "&" means a new variable on the query string so you ahve to urlencode the string when the page is loading. query strings look like this. ?var1=aa&var2=b&var3=c when you put the "&" on the query string you are breaking it.

Comment: I also found another fix to this :D updated post

Comment: Just another little comment to your new work around. If you alert(fixed); you will see its the same string as posted in my fix. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line here shows me you are loading flash vars.

```
homeTitle = this.loaderInfo.parameters.homeText;
```

For example if you have a url like so.

```
http://somedomain.com?var1=aa&var2=b&var3=c
```

There are 3 variable being passed to flash var1,var2,var3
When you do

```
http://somedomain.com?title=Quick & easy chicken recipes for dinner
```

You are breaking it in 2 spots the first spot is the ampersand that is telling flash there is a new variable to read. the other spot is the spaces, URLs can not have spaces.
so the proper way to encode this would be

```
http://somedomain.com?title=Quick%20%26%20easy%20chicken%20recipes%20for%20dinner
```

And then of course in flash an unescape() would be perfect.

Sorry I should have noticed this sooner it didn't dawn on me that the data isn't there.

Comment: Hey thanks! Looks like another fix I have to push off onto the Front end girl again. I'm going to rename this question to how to escape instead of search and replace.

Answer (score 2):

Try `unescape(homeTitle)` as escaping it is the opposite way you want to go.

example: `trace(unescape("%26")); //will trace out: &`

Comment: looks like both escape and unescape make my title look like "Quick%20" :( I think this is a major problem in Flash.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing this part for that unescape to work: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp